# TypeError: components.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the same components in two different places but one isnt working.

This is Board.js giving Error:

> TypeError: components.map is not a function

```
    const Board = () => {
        const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);

        const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
            accept: ItemTypes.COMPONENT,
            drop: (item) => {
                setComponents(components.push(item));
                console.log(components);
            },
        }));

        return (
            <div ref={drop} className="board">
                <Components components={components} />
            </div>
        );
    };
```

This is Components.js working fine

```
    const Components = ({ components }) => {
        return (
            <>
                {components.map(
                    (component) => (
                        <Component
                            key={
                                component.name
                            }
                            component={
                                component
                            }
                        />
                    )
                )}
            </>
        );
    };

    export default Components;
```

This is Category.js using Components.js working just fine

```
    const Category = ({ category }) => {
        const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);

        return (
            <div className="category">
                <h3 onClick={() => setShowContent(!showContent)}>
                    {category.name}
                    {showContent ? <FaTimes /> : <FaCaretDown />}
                </h3>
                {showContent ? <Components components={category.data} /> : <></>}
            </div>
        );
    };

    export default Category;
```

I dont know why Board.js is not working.
The data given to them is correct format.
can someone help me diagnose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem

```js
const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
            accept: ItemTypes.COMPONENT,
            drop: (item) => {
                //Here you are setting component to the return value of components.push
                //that is the new lenght of the array
                setComponents(components.push(item));
                console.log(components);
            },
        }));
```

You should instead do like this

```js
const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
            accept: ItemTypes.COMPONENT,
            drop: (item) => {
                setComponents(prev => [...prev, item]);
                console.log(components);
            },
        }));
```

Comment: This is a bad practice, you should not pass the current state to mutate the same state value with the ongoing `setState` operation generated by the `useState` hook.

instead you should use a callback to `prevState`, i.e. `setComponents(prevComponents => [...prevComponents, item])`. Doing it the way you implied could cause asynchronity between what's passed to state and what gets updated resulting in data incosistency

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally changed the type of your array to `Number` in the following line:

```
setComponents(components.push(item));
```

And albeit the initial log may imply your state mutated correctly, given `setState` operations are asynchronous may actually lead towards missing the bug altogether upon console.logging it.

If you look up the MDN of [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it returns the new length of array upon which it was called (hence the type number).

Change the all occurances of push to

```js
setComponents(prevComponents => [...prevComponents, item])
```

and it will work correctly